# C - Is there any way to check if a number is equal to 1 using bit checks?

Tags: c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit

This is more just a question of interest - I'm not sure how it would actually be applicable. Anyways - is it possible using bit-checks to see if a number is equal to 1?

Comment: @TomerArazy: That check passes 0 as well.

Comment: CPUs always work on bits anyways, so any method will do

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using bit-checks"? Does something like `((x ^ 1) >> 31) | (-(x ^ 1) >> 31)` count as "using bit-checks"?

Comment: @harold that's what I'm trying to look for, yeah.

Comment: `if (n == 1)` checks to see if the lowest bit is 1 and the rest are 0.

Comment: This sounds like an interview question. _"Check if a given number is equal to 1 without using conditionals."_

Comment: @AnishRam I wish, if I were good enough to apply for a job, maybe it would be :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what exactly the questions is, but you can use either `!(x ^ 1)` or `x == 1` or `!(x-1)` or `(x & 1) && !(x & ~1)` or one of many other ways.

Answer (score 1):

I think if(1==number) is enough. Internally a bit wise comparison is permormed.

Comment: Commonly, comparisons are implemented by an instruction that performs a subtraction and sets several bits describing the result (negative, zero, overflow, carry). So `1 == number` is likely to result in an actual arithmetic operation, not just a bitwise comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand the bit-checks. If you mean check the bit one-by-one, you can perform that in a loop. Or you can use the code:

```
int equalsOne(int a) {
    return (a && (a == !!a));
}
```

The `!` operator will return `0` for non-zero value else `1`. The leading `a` in the return statement eliminates the case where `a == 0`.